# SkipWhile method does not work as I expected in RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

```
boolean isRetryButtonClicked = false;

.retryWhen(throwableFlowable -> throwableFlowable.skipWhile(throwable -> !isRetryButtonClicked)
    .doOnNext(throwable -> Log.w("...", "doOnNext"))
    .doOnComplete(() -> Log.w("...", "doOnComplete"))
    .doOnError(throwable -> Log.w("...", "doOnError " + throwable))
    .doOnSubscribe(subscription -> Log.w("...", "doOnSubscribe")))
```

If the `isRetryButtonClicked` variable was false then it will not print doOnNext and that is okay because I told it to skip while `isRetryButtonClicked` equal false, But when the user clicks on the retry button I'll change the `isRetryButtonClicked` value to true, And after that it must start to print doOnNext but the current result is still not print anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`retryWhen` needs a signal to perform the retry from that inner source. However, `isRetryButtonClicked` is a field so changes to it are not signals. What you need is a `Subject`. For example:

```java
PublishSubject<String> subjectToRetry = PublishSubject.create();

source.retryWhen(errors -> errors.zipWith(subjectToRetry, (e, s) -> s))
    .doOnNext(throwable -> Log.w("...", "doOnNext"))
    .doOnComplete(() -> Log.w("...", "doOnComplete"))
    .doOnError(throwable -> Log.w("...", "doOnError " + throwable))
    .doOnSubscribe(subscription -> Log.w("...", "doOnSubscribe")))

// inside the retryButton's click handler:

subjectToRetry.onNext("Doit!");
```

Comment: One week ago I was asking always myself why 90% of developers suggest using the `zipWith` inside the `retryWhen`? I searched a lot on the internet about the `zipWith` but I did not understand it, Yesterday, I found a topic that explains it with a real example of how to use it, Eventually, I understood it, I'm happy after a lot of struggle. Now I can handle failed connections using `RxJava` easily. Thank you so much.

Comment: If you don't mind I want to ask you about the `repeatWhen`, I implemented [this feature](https://developer.android.com/training/swipe) inside my app and I want to subscribe again with the server when asking to refresh data, What about using the `repeatWhen`, Is it good with my scenario? As I understood `RxJava` can not call with the `repeatWhen` after observer methods are called, If the `repeatWhen` was not good with my scenario what you will suggest to me?